# Real time subtitle for react native app, its possible?

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, closed-captions

I'm trying to implement automatic subtitle generation in a React native app and I thought about a subtitle approach via streaming.

Calling some Google speech service, azure, etc ... and translating in real time that the video is playing

But I'm a little lost on how to do this with react native, could you help me?
Does anyone have any ideas or a lib not free that would solve this problem of automatic subtitle generation?

Have you been through this?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video) package solves your problem?

Comment: then, in parts but not much. Because you need to capture the audio send to a service and present the subtitle and its transcription in real time,

Comment: @Ricardo Junior, can you help to how it can be done real time sabtitle?